# Can you add a flat mat-fab button to an Angular app using Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am adding a [mat-fab](https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples) button to my Angular app from Angular Material:

```
<button mat-fab>
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
</button>
```

At the moment, the button is appearing like so:

[image]

But I want the button to appear flat (so the circle isn't visible, all that I want visible is the icon).

I've tried using the below code, but that's making no difference:

```
<button mat-flat-button mat-fab>
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Can someone please show me if it is possible to add the `flat` styling to a `mat-fab` button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `mat-icon-button` for the same

```
<button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Refer https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview for other styles

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

this is not a good aproach but you can use "::ng-deep" in **`your-component.css`** to fix this things.

e.g:

```
  ::ng-deep {
    .mat-flat-button {
    ...
    }
    }
```

**Beside this, You should read about angular material theming.**
 =>  https://material.angular.io/guide/theming